# Disable GNU gettext function "_()" temporarily in Python

Tags: python, gettext

I do use GNU gettext with its class based API which in consequence installs `_()` in Pythons `builtins` namespace. I want to disable the translation temporarily in a global scope.

I tried to somehow "mask" `_()` via shading it with a local function definition. But I got these error:

```
No problem.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ownCloud/_transfer/./z.py", line 27, in <module>
    .format(foobar(True), foobar(False)))
  File "/home/user/ownCloud/_transfer/./z.py", line 19, in foobar
    return _('Hello')
UnboundLocalError: local variable '_' referenced before assignment
```

This is the MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gettext

translation = gettext.translation(
    domain='iso_639',
    languages=['de'],
    localedir='/usr/share/locale'
)
translation.install()  # installs _() in "buildins" namespace
# Keep in mind: The object "translation" is not avialble in the original
# productive code because it is instanciated elsewhere.

def foobar(translate):
    if not translate:
        # I try to mask the global _() builtins-function
        def _(txt):
            return txt

    return _('Hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # To ilustrate that _() is part of "builtins" namespace
    print(_('No problem.'))

    print('The translated string "{}" is originally "{}".'
          .format(foobar(True), foobar(False)))
```

In my original productive code I try to display a big multi line string in two flavours: Untranslated and translated. But I don't want to duplicate that string in code like this.

```
original = 'Hello'
translated = _('Hello')
```

To my knowledge the GNU gettext utilities do need the second line to figuring out which strings are translatable and should go into the `po`/`pot` files. Because of that I can not do it like this because gettext utils don't know what `original` is.

```
original = 'Hello'
translated = _(original)
```

Maybe I try it the wrong way. Alternativily I could formulate my question with: *How can I display one string in its original source (untranslated) form and translated site by site without duplicating the string in the python source code?*

Comment: Don't you have an infinite recursion?

Comment: Excellent eyes! Modified the question. The original problem is still there.

Comment: If you define `_` conditionally in a function, `_` becomes a function-scoped variable that has nothing in common with global `_` any more.

Comment: I understand that somehow. But how can I mask/disable `_()`?

Comment: Might it be possible to manipulate the buildints namespace somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
def N_(msgid):
    return msgid


original = N_(msgid)
translated = _(msgid)
```

You just have to configure your message extractor to also extract arguments to the function `N_`.

If you extract your messages with `xgettext` which ships with GNU gettext you have to add that keyword explicitely with `--keyword=N_` (which is a little bit annoying because it is a default keyword for most language but not for Python).  If you are using PyBabel it *is* a default keyword, see https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/cmdline.html#extract.

In case, the code does not make sense, here's a more in-depth explanation: All gettext translation functions (`gettext()`, `ngettext()`, `pgettext()`, `_()`, ...) serve a double purpose: At runtime, they provide a translation for the message in question. At "message extraction time", they mark strings as translatable. The function `N_()` conventionally just marks strings but does not actually retrieve a translation at runtime.

But why does the extractor not get triggered by `_(msgid)`? Because the extractor only extracts string literals but never variables.  At runtime, the argument to `_()`/`gettext()` and friends is a lookup key into a (static) message catalogue and it obviously has to be constant.

Note: I'm not a Python guru and therefore have no idea whether you have to define the no-op function `N_()` yourself or if it is available by default.  You will find that out yourself.